# How can I estimate or calculate the processing fee when I upload a file using IPFS?

Tags: javascript, storage, ethereum, blockchain, ipfs

I want to implement IPFS in my javascript based project but before that I wanted to know about the calculation or processing fees when I upload a file using my javascript application using IPFS.

I tried to collect the required information from IPFS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

IPFS itself has no pricing attached, it uses similar model to torrents. Uploads to own nodes are free.

Check your service provider for their pricing.